# Raising numbers to fractional powers in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to raise a series of numbers to a fractional (1/5) power in MS SQL, yet I'm getting a 'domain error' when applying to a negative base.

This shouldn't be a problem since I'm raising to an odd-powered root.  Further, I'm able to do the calculation in Excel.

Can anyone comment on whether MS SQL simply doesn't support raising negative powers to fractional roots?

Comment: The documentation for MSSQL 2000 implies that this is totally fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276880(v=SQL.80).aspx.

Comment: Are you really saying you're trying to do calculations with complex numbers?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276880(v=sql.80).aspx Isn't this definitive?  What more do you need?

Comment: Looks like you have to work around it as here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic239436-8-1.aspx#bm962649

Comment: You don't raise powers to roots: you raise bases to powers and extract roots. Did you mean "raising negative bases to fractional powers"?

Comment: @S.Lott - Far from being definitive the documentation you link to doesn't address this issue. If anything it probably implies that it would be supported as the first commenter interpreted it.

Comment: @Martin: It would be more clear if the question actually included actual code and actual error messages.  Until then, all we have to go on is the documentation.  From the broken terminology in the question, I'm unable to see how the documentation fails to address the.  If you could provide some details of the mismatch between question and documentation, that might help.

Comment: @S. Lott - Well I interpreted the question as asking whether `SELECT POWER(-32, 1.0/5)` was supported. The documentation doesn't definitively say it isn't but it doesn't work!

Comment: @Oli - Unless I'm missing something, your link says nothing about the scenario I'm referencing. 

@pavium - I think you're misunderstanding or need to revist fractional powers -- -2^(1/5) doesn't induce a complex number.

Comment: @Oli/S. Lott - Unless I'm missing something, your links say nothing about the scenario I'm referencing. 

@pavium - I think you're misunderstanding -- -2^(1/5) doesn't induce a complex number. 

@Martin - Great workaround...thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Negative base raised into a fractional power would result in a complex number which `SQL Server` does not support.

You can raise a negative base into an integer power:

```
SELECT  POWER(-3, 3)
```

or a positive base into a fractional power:

```
SELECT  POWER(9, 1.5)
```

Comment: They wouldn't for odd roots though. The cube root of -27 is -3

Comment: @Martin: the only problem left is to provide exact `1/3` as an argument to `POWER`.

Comment: @Martin: The cube root of -27 is indeed -3 (actually one the three cube roots). But `POWER(-27, 1/3)` is different than the imaginary `ROOT(-27,3)`. Since fractional numbers are not supported by SQL-Server, the `1/3` would be a float, something like `0.3333333`. So `POWER(-27, 0.3333333)` is rightly not supported, is it?

Comment: Yes. Agreed that this is the nub of the problem!

Comment: @Martin: also note that `-3` is only one of the three cube roots of `-27`, the other two being complex.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your last statement is right, since it is the case with MySql and Oracle.

**EDIT**

To everyone saying this results in complex numbers : raising a number to 1/3 is like a cubic root, which returns no complex numbers... so raising to 1/5, 1/7... wouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

When base is negative and power is fractional with odd denominator, you can raise (-base) to the (fractional power) and then take the minus of the result.

In other words, **SQL Server simply doesn't support raising negative bases to fractional powers**.

And rightly so, I should add.

Comment: Why don't they support it? I'd like to take the cubic root of my possibly negative-valued input.  It's not a complex (a*r+b*i) number - why confuse the matter.  The roots are defined.

Comment: @ColinMac The roots are defined, yes. Mind there are 3 cubic roots of each number. Two of them are complex. Note that I state that SQL Server does not allow raising to **fractional** powers. It only allows raising to powers of type float and so there is no easy way to allow negative bases.