# Error using power function when the base is negative and exponent is fractional

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server's [POWER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) function in a user function and when the base is a negative number and the exponent is a fraction I'm getting an error,

> [MICROSOFT][ODBC SQL SERVER DRIVER][SQL SERVER]AN INVALID FLOATING POINT OPERATION OCCURRED.

A negative base can be raised to a power in the real world, so is this an SQL bug? If so is there a work around?

Example:

```
SELECT POWER(-.2, 9.7)
```

Further refinement of the issue

```
-- These work
SELECT 
    POWER(-.2, 9)
,   POWER(.2, 9.7);

-- This does not
SELECT
    POWER(-.2, 9.7);

-- POWER on BOL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx
-- Returns the same type as submitted in float_expression
-- Perhaps something is awry with typing
DECLARE
    @f decimal(35,30) = -.2
,   @fout decimal(35,30);

-- This still fails with "An invalid floating point operation occurred"
SELECT
    @fout = POWER(@f, 9.7);
```

Comment: The SQL_Server implementation is fine. The windows calculator is broken.

Comment: FWIW, Calculator on Windows 7 gives an "Invalid input" error.

Comment: Mea culpa, I edited the question and added the further refinement section which include the windows calculator line. @DStanley I also fail windows calculator as it applied the `-` to the results of `.2^9.7`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `POWER(-.2, 9.7)` would be, at best, an imaginary number, and cannot be represented as a single floating-point number.

You *could* convert the floating-point exponent to a fraction and rewrite it as `POWER(-.2,97/10)` which is equivalent to `POWER(POWER(-.2,97) , 1/10)`.  Since the Nth roots of a negative number are real if N is odd but imaginary if N is even, `POWER(-.2,1/10)` would be a complex number.

Note that `POWER(-.2, 0.8)` *could* be evaluated as a real number since it would just be equivalent to `POWER(-.2,4/5)` and the 5th root of -.2 is real, but my guess is that SQL doesn't even bother trying to determine if the exponent could be represented as a fraction with an odd denominator and throws an error.

Comment: I believe converting the decimal to a fraction is the correct work around. It isn't an issue any more because a decision was made to re-write the function. Since this function was first written a more accurate way to get the number has been created.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SQL Server just does not let you do fractional exponents for negative base numbers.

There's some discussion here: [Raising numbers to fractional powers in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838212/raising-numbers-to-fractional-powers-in-sql)

I did some testing, just to see what works and what doesn't, using this query:

```
create table #test(b float, val float, success bit default (0));

    declare @a float = -1, @b decimal(3,2) = 0.01

    WHILE @b < 2
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #test(b) VALUES(@b);

        BEGIN TRY
            UPDATE #test SET val = POWER(@a, @b), success = 1 WHERE b = @b
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT @@error
        END CATCH

        SELECT @b += .01;
    END

    select * from #test
```

If you notice, even steps that should work without giving a complex number error out. The only result that works correctly is 1.